# Asp.net Web API - Add attribute to each controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

I have a project with an ASP.net Web API. Now i have created a custom attribute. I can set that attribute for each controller, but how can i set it on each controller at once? Is there something for in the startup class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the [`App_Start > WebApiConfig.cs`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api) file.

In the Register `method`  add this line:

```
config.Filters.Add(new MyCustomAttribute());
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. You can use a base controller and use it as a base class on every of your other controllers.**

```
    [YourCustomAttribute]
    public class BaseController : ApiController 
    {
    }

    public class HomeController : BaseController 
    {
    }
```

**2. Another solution is to use [Conditional Filters in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/)**

Using this solution you can add the attribute without a base class.